# What is the difference between update and updateMany method in mongo DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update multiple documents on mongo db. which is better update method with multi = true or updateMany method? and what is the difference between them?

Comment: I suspect one is the wrapper for the other.

Comment: As per change log (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/) : It is  Equivalent to db.collection.update( <query>, <update>, { multi: true, ... }) method with an <update> document that specifies modifications using update operators and the multi option set to true.

Comment: What @SergioTulentsev said is the most true statement. It's mainly about the distinction for `.updateOne()` and `.updateMany()` which respectively either "omit" the `"multi"` option within the "wrapped" `.update()` or "include" it explicitly. Some driver documentation marks `.update()` as deprecated, but this is not entirely true, since **all** of those drivers actually call `.update()` within the implentation of their `.updateOne()` and `.updateMany()` methods. It's nothing but semantics really, and both are really just the same.

Answer (score 15):

To expand on [Blakes Seven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/blakes-seven)'s answer, all the `updateOne` method does is simply set the `multi` option to `false` as seen [here (github)](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/lib/collection.js#L900).

And in turn all the `updateMany` method does is set the `multi` opion to `true` as seen [here (github)](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/lib/collection.js#L1012).

So there is no "better" method to call, just pick whichever you feel suits the situation.

Comment: `updateOne` updates the first document if multiple documents match the query

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that `update()` by default, modifies only one document matching the specified filter. However, you can make it modify all the documents by adding the `modifier {multi: true}`. `updateMany` on the other hand, modifies all the documents matching a specified filter.

Answer (score 6):

“updateOne” and “updateMany” are newer APIs and should be used if possible instead of “update”.

In the book “Mongo Definitive Guide” (while talking about “updateOne”):

“The update document must contain update operators. Previous versions of the CRUD API did not catch this type of error. Earlier update methods would simply complete a whole document replacement in such situations. It is this type of pitfall that led to the creation of a new CRUD API.”

— MongoDB: The Definitive Guide: Powerful and Scalable Data Storage by Shannon Bradshaw, Eoin Brazil, et al.

Answer (score 2):

**updateMany()** and **updateOne()**

```
updateMany(query, update, options) => Modifies ALL the doc's which matches the query.
updateOne(query, update, options)  => Modifies a SINGLE first doc which matches the query.
```

updateMany() and updateOne() **options:**

```
{
    upsert: <boolean>,
    writeConcern: <document>,
    collation: <document>,
    arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
}
```

**update():**

```
update(query, update, options)    => Modifies a SINGLE first doc which matches the query. 
              (DEFAULT behaviour. But you could used as a "updateMany()" or "updateOne()" 
               by changing the "multi: <boolean>" inside options)
```

update() **options:**

```
{
    multi: <boolean>,   // multi: true  => became => updateMany() 
                        // multi: false => became => updateOne()

    upsert: <boolean>,
    writeConcern: <document>,
    collation: <document>,
    arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One difference which I found missing in previous answers is `update()` does not require `$set` to be used and w/o `$set` it actually erases all the existing data in document and replaces it with the data you provide.

While `updateMany()` & `updateOne()` actually need `$set` to be specified w/o `$set` you will get an error like `uncaught exception: Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators`

It totally depends on your use case though.

Answer (score -3):

updateOne() --> update only one document in a collection.

updateMany() --> update many document in a collection with given filter.